# How to change a tuple within a value of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary of the format :

```
d[key] = [(val1, (Flag1, Flag2)),
          (val2, (Flag1, Flag2)),
          (val3, (Flag1, Flag2))]
```

I want to make it :

```
d[key] = [(val1, Flag1),
          (val2, Flag1),
          (val3, Flag1)]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
d[key] = [(x, y[0]) for x,y in d[key]]
```

Simple version:

```
new_val = []
for x, y in d[key]:
   #In each iteraion x is assigned to VALs and `y` is assigned to (Flag1, Flag2)
   #now append a new value, a tuple containg x and y[0](first item from that tuple) 
   new_val.append((x, y[0]))
d[key] = new_val  #reassign the new list to d[key]
```

To modify the whole dictionary:

```
dic = { k: [(x, y[0]) for x,y in v]  for k,v in dic.items()}
```

In py2.x you can use `dic.iteritems` as it returns an iterator, `dic.items()` will work on both py2x and py3x.

Comment: Can you explain it a little please?

Comment: WIll it do for all the key:value pairs?

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta notice `(x, val[0])` , `val[1]` is discarded in list compression.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan will it do that for all the key value pairs?

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta It does not. If you want to do it on all the keys, wrap the line in a for loop that loops over all the keys.

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta: You will have to iterate over all the key value pairs in the dictionary.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary will it be `d[key] = [(x, val[0]) for x,y in d[key]]` or `d[key] = [(x, y[0]) for x,y in d[key]]` ?

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta oops! typo: `d[key] = [(x, y[0]) for x,y in d[key]]`

Answer (score 8):

Using `tuple` unpacking:

```
d[key] = [(x, y) for (x, (y, z)) in d[key]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Should work for all items:

```
d = { k: [(x, y) for (x, (y, z)) in v] for k,v in d.iteritems() }
```

You might want to read: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions